# Stack Overflowはどうやって収益をえてるの?

Tags: 討議

広告とか見当たらないから気になる。

運用コストはゼロではないはずなので、どこかでお金を得ないと続けられないと思うけど、そのあたりどういう仕組になってるのかしら。

Answer (score 9):

[What is Stack Overflow's business model? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

によれば、

- 雇用情報の掲載(昔からあるような求人広告)による収入
  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-listings
- 雇用できそうな候補者の検索サービス(最近はやりのマッチング)による収入
  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-search
- 昔からあるけど馬鹿にはできない、広告(Flashは使わない)による収入
  http://stackexchange.com/mediakit

が柱だそうで、その気になればどれくらい売り上げてるか計算できそうですね、と書いてありました。日本語版でも本サービスが開始されれば、こうしたモデルで収益を上げるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: [最新のPodcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/02/podcast-62-delete-this-whole-episode/)では更に情報があります（英語のみですが）。基本的にCareersが一番大きいと言っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Andreessen Horowitzから調達したっていう記事も読みました。勉強になります！